# matching different sized strings

Tags: java, string-matching

Actually I went through research docuements and i got a situation match binary string with another binary string size is uknown
ex:

```
"1110000010001001101011010100010000101101001001010010000101000011"==
"1011010111010111111111010101100000000000101111101100011010011011"
```

I want result as TRUE if any string matches with most significant bits of another string

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Please provide more examples. How many MSBs do you want to compare?

Comment: Is your example supposed to return true or false ? 
both bit strings have the first bit in common. Is that significant enough ?

Comment: If you got them as a String, look into [String.startsWith](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith). Also, don't compare Strings using the `==` operator in Java.

Comment: and don't compare string with ==

Comment: Entire string Ex:str1="100101" str2="10101010" now it should check if entire str1 present in str2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare one MSB, just compare first character as below:

```
boolean result = number1.charAt(0) == number2.charAt(0);
```

For multiple MSBs, use the following code:

```
int noOfMSBs = 8;
boolean result = number1.substring(0, noOfMSBs - 1).equals(number2.substring(0, noOfMSBs - 1));
```

To compare if whole number is present as MSB in another string:

```
boolean result = number2.startsWith(number1);
```

Answer (score 0):

EDITED after comment on question :

To test if a string starts with another, just use `startsWith` :

```
boolean result = str2.startsWith(str1);
// results if true if str2 starts with full str1 string.
```

ORIGINAL

I think you should can cut your strings and compare the first part.

```
String str1, str2;
int numSignificantBits = xxx;
significantPart1 = str1.subString(0, numSignificantBits);
significantPart2 = str2.subString(0, numSignificantBits);
if (significantPart1.equals(significantPart2)) 
{
    // ok
}
```

Of course, you should add proper checking for null or string too shorts.

And also, don't compare strings wiht `==` in java! Use the `String.equals`function.